# How to develop Firefox addon that adds tab to firefox native developer tools (not firebug)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools

I am trying to create addon for firefox that will add some functionality to firefox developer tools. similar to Ember inspector (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ember-inspector/)

Is there any good tutorial or sample of code that will guide me through creating a hello world addon that will add a tab into firefox developer tools.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you look at the page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools under the heading Extending the devtools

Comment: @epascarello yes I've seen that, but where is an example or tutorial for adding a tab into devtools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on [twitter](https://twitter.com/gozala/status/507577062182248448), check out these example extensions:

- https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/tree/master/examples/actor-repl
- https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/tree/master/examples/debug-client